# Is I/O priority propagated to child processes?

Tags: process-priority

I recently found out about `ionice`. If I run a script which in turn runs processes will the priorities of the child processes be equal to the parent script? If not, is there a way to set priorities for the child processes together?

**UPDATE**

Niceness does propagate as answered on [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37896/nice-and-child-processes). Does the I/O priority do too?

Comment: ionice != nice. One is CPU scheduling priority, the other is input/output scheduling priority.

Comment: I didn't know that. However, the question is the same minus the incorrect `nice` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both ionice and nice values are inherited by the children of a process. In the future, you can test things like this by running the following command to test and print the ionice value of a process and compare to its parent:

```
ionice -p $pid
```

These questions on unix.stackexchange and superuser have more information on the subject:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37896/nice-and-child-processes

https://superuser.com/questions/63091/do-children-processes-inherit-ionice-priorities-from-their-parents-how-do-you-c